# Why doesn't the value passed to a method of a different class reflect in Java (using NetBeans 7.01)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, actionlistener

Before I start, Hi. This is is my first question here. I am not good with Java so have been trying and improve that and here it goes.

I am trying to create an email client and server application using sockets in Java. However I have been running into a problem. I have created a jFrame which is basically the Welcome window. The code is too huge to post so I'll post the relevant portions. There is a preferences jDialog. When the OK button on the dialog, an action handler comes in to play. The code:

```
 private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        Welcome wel = new Welcome();
        wel.setStatusBar("Pressed OK");
        dispose();
    }
```

Obviously, the setStatusBar() sets the text of the statusLabel. The code for setStatusBar():

```
public void setStatusBar(String s)
{

    statusLabel.setText(s);

}
```

Also, the preferences dialog is opened through menu item with this code:

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    settings pref=new settings(null,true);
    pref.show();
}
```

The problem is if I set the status label from any other class, for instance settings class, it does not reflect but if I do so from the Welcome class ( the class where the statusLabel is present), it works fine. This problem is not only limited to this setStatus() but virtually pops up whenever I try to use a method of a different class.

If you guys need more of the code, I could post it. I would be grateful if could help a Java beginner out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Welcome wel = new Welcome();
    wel.setStatusBar("Pressed OK");
    dispose();
}
```

You're creating a **new** (hence the keyword `new`) object of type `Welcome`. This *new* object is different from the already existing object of type `Welcome`, that you have created earlier. It thus has its own label, and you're setting the text of this different label, which is not displayed anywhere in the screen.

Java objects work like regular object. Let's say you would like a cool logo on one of your blue t-shirts. You go to a T-shirt vendor and ask him to print a cool logo. The vendor doesn't have your blue t-shirt. If the vendor gets another red t-shirt from his shop and prints the logo on this red t-shirt, your blue t-shirt will still have no logo at all.

For the vendor to be able to print a logo on your blue t-shirt, you need to give him this blue t-shirt. Same in Java: you need to pass the existing Welcome object to the preferences dialog, and the actionPerformed method must set the label on this Welcome object. Not on a new Welcome object.

Comment: You just made me feel extremely stupid. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It takes everybody some time to grasp OO concepts. A real-life analogy often causes the tilt to happen. I'm glad if that was the case for you.

Comment: I got it to work. For the sake of lifting my confidence, what would be the ideal way?. Currently I am passing it in the constructor.

Comment: That's the obvious and natural way to do it.